# Why notification text is not shown in Android 7.0(Nougat)

Tags: android, push-notification, android-7.0-nougat

I am displaying `notification` in my app which is working fine in all the `OS versions` except `Android 7.0`(**Nougat**) Here is the code

```
  Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, HomeScreenActivity.class);

        // set intent so it does not start a new activity
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

        PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, new Intent(), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL | Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS);

        Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(context);
        builder.setContentIntent(intent)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setStyle(new Notification.BigTextStyle().bigText(message))
                .setContentText(message);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21)
            builder.setVibrate(new long[0]);

        notification.flags = Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS | Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP){
            builder.setColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
            builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_nav_reward_point);
        }else{
            builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.launcher_icon);
        }
        builder.setAutoCancel(true);
        builder.setContentIntent(intent);
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

        // Play default notification sound
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

         // Vibrate if vibrate is enabled
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;

        notification = builder.build();
        notificationManager.notify(m, notification);
```

In `Android 7.0` i am able to see the `notification icon`, title but it's not showing the complete notification text.

Is there anything that I am missing for `Android 7.0`? Any help will deeply appreciate.

Comment: Hi did you figure out the solution ?